# REST client that does not need installation

Tags: rest, rest-client

We have a locked down customer environment in which we do not have rights to install anything. In this environment, I need to call some REST services in order to troubleshoot them.

In my local development environment, I normally use Postman (Chrome plugin) or Advanced REST client. However, since the customer environment is locked down, I can't install Chrome (they have IE 11) or Adv. REST client.

Is there any REST client that I can just copy and use, without the need for installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am under the same constraints. To test a `RESTful API`, I installed a portable Chrome version(doesn't require admin permission) in which I installed postman.

You can find a portable chrome edition with a simple google search.

You can also install a portable firefox edition and install a plugin to simulate REST requests like `HttpRequester` [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/).

You can also use SOAP UI from here https://www.soapui.org/. Make sure to choose the open source version for a free edition. Also, when installing making sure to change the installation path to a folder you have permission to write in, for instance a folder in your Desktop. Here's the doc on how to use it: https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/soapui-projects.html

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. It seems they have blocked access to Chrome and Firefox plugins as well. Is there a portable REST client that I can just copy on this machine without having to install a plugin?

Comment: Or may be a web based version of REST client that does not need a plugin to be installed.